# text highlighting (from scratch) output issue

Tags: javascript, highlighting

I'm trying to build a simple color highlighter using a textarea calling a function on keyup, and a div to output the result (highlighted/colored text).

The words to be highlighted and their associated color are stored in this object :

```
var obj = {
  "to": "green",
  "code": "red",
  "applet": "blue"
}
```

The input string is then split into word units to check if they match the `obj` keys.

```
var splitRequest = input.value.toLowerCase().split(' ');
```

If they do, then they should be highlighted. I wrote a simple code that does the trick (see fiddle at the end), except for this line :

```
output.innerHTML += '<span style="color:' + obj[splitRequest[i]] + '">' + splitRequest[i] + " </span>";
```

It prints the whole text on each keypress instead of replacing the current content with the new one because of the `+=` sign. Problem is that I can't simply use the `=` sign because it will only print the first element of the `splitRequest` array instead of the whole array. I tried to use the `join()` method but it obviously didn't work as I expected ([test](https://jsfiddle.net/Lau1989/tnqdv233/)).

Maybe the code itself isn't so good and I should use another approach to get it working. This would be a great way to learn javascript better, but I actually have no idea how to do this.

How can I output the text user types in while highlighting the matching words without having this problem ?

Here is the working demo where I'm stuck : https://jsfiddle.net/Lau1989/9oL7umtt/1/

Thanks for your help

PS : I know there are third-parties availables for syntax highlighting, but for the sake of educating myself I'm trying to code it from scratch using pure javascript (no jQuery).

Comment: The `<font>` tag has been [deprecated in HTML 4.01](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font). You should not be using it anymore. Replace it with: `<span style="color:...">...</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

`output.innerHTML = "";`

after

`var output = document.getElementById('output');`

on LINE 9

https://jsfiddle.net/Lauy79kv/

Comment: Oh my god... I aleady tried this but addded it in the wrong line (inside the for loop). It works fine now, thank you !

Comment: no problemo. lots of the most difficult bugs are caused by the simplest things -- thats why they have QA

Answer (score 1):

here is a working solution

```
var obj = {
    "to": "green",
    "code": "red",
    "applet": "blue"
}

function highlight() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var output = document.getElementById('output'),
        pattern = /\s+(to|code|applet)(?=\s+)/gi;

    output.innerHTML = input.value.replace(pattern, function (x) {
       return "<span style=\"color:" + obj[x.toLowerCase().trim()] +
           "\"> " + x + "</span>" });
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I was just trying to use regExp in my code. Is there any way to make the pattern dynamically match the object properties using a variable instead of using predefined keys ? Something like `for (var prop in obj) { pattern =  /\s+(/ + prop + /)(?=\s+)/gi; }`  instead of `(to|code|applet)` would be great. I'm having trouble finding the right syntax as I'm not so familiar with RegExp yet.

Comment: see in the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.
                var obj = {
            "to": "green",
            "code": "red",
            "applet": "blue"
        }

```
    props = [];
    for (var p in obj) {
        props.push(p);
    }
    var pat = new RegExp("\\s+(" + props.join("|") + ")(?=\\s+)", "gi");
    alert(pat);
    function highlight() {
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.innerHTML = input.value.replace(pat, function (x) { return "<span style=\"color:" + obj[x.toLowerCase().trim()] + "\"> " + x + "</span>" });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of ES2015/ES6 style, using map/reduce and string templating.

```js
'use strict'

const obj = {
  "to": "green",
  "code": "red",
  "applet": "blue"
}

const output = document.getElementById('output')
document.getElementById('input')
  .addEventListener('keyup', highlight)

/**
 * Process text and provides provides that text in output control
 */
function highlight() {
  output.innerHTML = processText(input.value.toLowerCase())
}

/**
 * Process text and returns formatted HTML text to be displayed
 *
 * @param {string} text - text to be processed
 * @return {string} - formatted HTML text
 */
function processText(text) {
  return text.split(' ')
    .map(x => obj[x] ? `<span style="color: ${obj[x]}">${x}</span>` : x)
    .reduce((prev, cur) => `${prev} ${cur}`)
}

/**
 * Trigger first time hightlight function
 * so it will highlight text if there is any text in input contol
 */
highlight()
```

```css
textarea {
  padding: 10px;
}
div {
  width: 235px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="30" rows="5" id="input" autofocus>To code or not to code this Applet</textarea>

<div id="output"></div>
```